# Prove that $a_n$ is increasing?

Tags: calculus

Can anyone help me with next step? I'm already at this step, how should I change this to solve the problem when $a_n$ is grater than $1$?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You can format maths using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: $\frac{n-1}{n}\cdot \frac{n+1}{n}=\frac{n^2-1}{n^2}$. You're missing the $^2$ in the denominator in your last expression.

Comment: You will need the inequality by Bernoulli.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner in which point of my equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(1+\frac{1}{n+1})^{n+1}}{(1+\frac{1}{n})^n}=\frac{n^n(n+2)^{n+1}}{(n+1)^{2n+1}}=\left(\frac{n(n+2)}{(n+1)^2}\right)^n\frac{n+2}{n+1} \\=\left(1-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right)^n\frac{n+2}{n+1}\ge\left(1-\frac{n}{(n+1)^2}\right)\frac{n+2}{n+1}=\frac{(n+2)(n^2+n+1)}{(n+1)^3}=\frac{n^3+3n^2+3n+2}{n^3+3n^2+3n+1}>1.
$$
Hence, $\{a_n\}$ is strictly increasing.

**Note.** We have used the inequality
$$
(1+a)^m\ge 1+ma, \quad a>-1, \,\,m\in\mathbb N.
$$